# Как проверить является ли натуральное число степенью двойки в Python

Tags: python

Как проверить является ли натуральное число степенью двойки в Python

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 14):

```
(n & (n-1) == 0) and n != 0
```

Answer (score 10):

Автор выше прав. Объясню математику.

Натуральное число, представленное степенью двойки, имеет в своей двоичной записи одну единицу

Например:

`n: 10000000, 01000000, 00100000, ..., 00000001`

Что будет, если от такого числа отнимем единицу?

`n-1: 01111111, 00111111, 00011111, ..., 00000000`

Теперь, взяв and между n и n-1, мы получим все нули в двоичной записи. Для числа, не являющегося степенью двойки, мы не получим настолько "инвертированные" записи. По аналогии с десятичной системой: только отняв от круглого числа вроде 10000 или 1000 единицу, мы получим в результате все девятки.

Проверку на n=0 можно не делать, так как по условию задачи n - натуральное. То есть итоговое решение будет выглядеть как:

`(n & (n-1) == 0)`